# cdh6.3.2 start cloudera-scm-agent will result in Generate a large number of RMAdminCLI into town, Until it runs out of system memory

Tags: cloudera-cdh

The Hadoop and Cloudera processes were shut down without shutting down, causing some problems.
Cluster two nodes contain hostname: w01-uat,w01-uat.
After the host is restarted, w01-UAT cannot check the host status on the CDH page.
so i run follow in shell:

```
sudo su -
jps
```

then show like this:

```
...
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
RMAdminCLI
...
```

and Until it runs out of mainframe memory.

when i reboot w01-uat,and when i run

```
systemctl restart cloudera-scm-agent
```

jps will add a lot of "RMAdminCLI".

Oddly, sometimes JPS displays a large number of Runjars.

summary:
When I start the agent, there's always a program that runs out of memory, like "Runjars" or "RMAdminCLI"
and hive hadoop cannot use.
so I had to shut down the cloudera-scm-agent.
The cluster was healthy and available before the abnormal shutdown.
w02-uat is healthy.
w01-uat is not healthy.
What should I do to make the cluster run properly?
why generate a lot of "RunJar" or "RMAdminCLI" ?

some message:
web ui:
[image]

when i start cloudera-scm-agent:
[image]
and
[image]

stop agent cannot stop "RMAdminCLI" but not add more RMAdminCLI.
[image]

Comment: Last year, the CDH was installed using the online method, but this year it seems that the official does not allow it

Comment: for solve w01-uat not healthy,i run some sheel like follow: ```rm -rf  /var/lib/cloudera-scm-agent/cm_guid```, ```kill -9 $(pgrep -f supervisord) ```,```systemctl stop supervisord```.